# Add an option to skip the "add picture" step when inserting an image into a post

Tags: feature-request, images, editor

Since a few months ago, one can paste or drag and drop the images directly into the editor:

[image: paste or drag and drop images into WYSIWYG editor]

However, for each inserted image, one still has to click on "Add picture". It would be nice to add an option to remove the "add picture" step when inserting an image into a post.

For example, Gmail and GitHub don't ask any confirmation from the user before uploading the image.

---

Related: [Browser extension to skip the "Add picture" step when adding an image to a Stack Exchange question or answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/57008/903).

Comment: But then I would loose the preview, right?

Comment: @rene you would lose the preview before uploading but you'd still have the preview of your post below or on the side of the editor.

Comment: It's interesting that the suggestion attracted so many downvotes while I haven't seen any complaint against GitHub.

Comment: Did you check Twitter? Most complaints about features are logged there ...

Comment: My guts told me I would loose functionality due to the change you propose. After reading Animuson's answer I was convinced I didn't want this feature implemented and downvoted accordingly. It is unfortunate that github took a different approach specially because [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1975362/54916628-3df88b00-4efa-11e9-8eb4-9971e9153d49.png) is an image I uploaded in an issue in a private repository. You're right: Github dropped the ball there.

Answer (score 10):

You could easily argue that the extra step isn't necessary for any of the input methods - once we have the image just insert it. However, I would argue that regardless of the person's preference, it's still an important step to confirm they provided the correct image.

At this step it *hasn't yet been uploaded* to Imgur's servers and they can potentially prevent leaking things they shouldn't before it instantly becomes more of a hassle to clean up. If we skip that step, it's already been uploaded and deleting the image is way more of a headache than saying "woops that's not what I wanted to paste."

Anyone can make that mistake, even people who hate the extra button click. There have been plenty of times that I've pasted something thinking I had something else in the clipboard.

Comment: That's why make it optional makes the most sense. Some people are ok to take the risk. For example, github.com doesn't ask any confirmation from the user before uploading the image.

Comment: That doesn't mean we should follow in their footsteps. I will say it flat-out: we would *never* add a new profile preference for something so minor. That's a waste of time and resources. If it's really such an annoyance to users, we'd likely spend a bit of time evaluating how many people ever cancel uploading an image and make a determination to either leave it as-is or remove the extra step entirely. We've always had a strong policy against adding preferences for every little thing.